# How to ensure that the matrix total is not filtered by slices in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want my matrix total not to be filtered when selecting any filter. How can this be implemented?

Comment: You need to write a specific measure for that matrix that would check if matrix column(s) are in the current scope and if not, calculate the value while removing the filters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correct, you need to create a new **Measure** using the function **ISINSCOPE** as below-

```
total_new = 
if(
    ISINSCOPE(your_table_name[your_filtercolumn_name]), 
    calculate(sum(your_table_name[Value])),
    calculate(
        sum(your_table_name[Value]),
        REMOVEFILTERS(your_table_name)
    )
)
```

You can see the output in the below image where **total_new** column is showing the grand total where as the **total** column showing the total for filtered id only.

[image]

You can check this very good tutorial on this [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sM6_ewDw2dY)